# How to log in into Redmine using REST API

Tags: web-services, redmine, redmine-api

I have the requirement to log in into Redmine using the REST API. Is it possible to login in Redmine using REST API? How can I handle it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the [Redmine API wiki](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api) you can see the following:

> Most of the time, the API requires authentication. To enable the API-style authentication, you have to check Enable REST API in Administration -> Settings -> Authentication.
>
> Then, authentication can be done in 2 different ways:
>
> - **using your regular login/password via HTTP Basic authentication.**
> - using your API key which is a handy way to avoid putting a password in a script.
>
> The API key may be attached to each request in one of the following way:
>
> - passed in as a "key" parameter
> - passed in as a username with a random password via HTTP Basic authentication
> - passed in as a "X-Redmine-API-Key" HTTP header (added in Redmine 1.1.0)
>
> You can find your API key on your account page ( /my/account ) when logged in, on the right-hand pane of the default layout.

If you want to use **[HTTP Basic Authentication](http://theadmin.org/articles/redmine-api-testing-for-the-authentication-key/)** you could use this:

```
1.HTTP Basic auth – http://login:password@redmine.org/issues.xml
2.HTTP Basic auth with API token and login – http://login:RANDOM_KEY@redmine.org/issues.xml- (not supported yet)
3.HTTP Basic auth with API token – http://RANDOM_KEY:X@redmine.org/issues.xml
4.Full token auth – http://redmine.org/issues.xml?key=RANDOM_KEY
```

Comment: Yes I did that already, But i want login with my user name and password using rest API.
Is it possible to do that.

Comment: @RandhirSingh I've bolded the part in my answer that answers your question.

Comment: Yes but how can I can do it, you tell me some example or for that ??

Comment: I just want to check that the requested username and password are from my redmine database .

Comment: I want to use http://login:password@redmine.org/issues.xml what do I have to set in user:password. My domain is http://redmine.geminus-qhom.com/redmine/